# How to get a view from an Activity similar to a TabHost

Tags: android

I am trying to make an Accordian control where each section would have its own view accompanied with its own activity.  With the TabHost I can add tabs based on Intents and it is this behavior I am trying to understand how to use.  So given an intent or an activity how can i get the view?

Answer (score 1):

When building things like that, you maybe want to use the `ActivityGroup` class, which allows you to manipulate a group of activities. There, you can do things like:

```
// this will give you the view
View view = getLocalActivityManager()
    .startActivity("NewsActiviy", intentRoot)
    .getDecorView();
```

If you are working directly from an `Activity`, and want to get its view, you will do something like this:

```
// this will give you the view
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
```